How to edit the bounty description?
I added a bounty to the following question: Has anyone formally tested Josh Pellicer's theory on human sexual behavior?, however I made a typo in the bounty description. How does the original bounty poster edit the bounty description?

This does not seem possible, and has been requested on the main meta site before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text

This is a perfect lay question with a perfect answer. We should hold it up as a shining example of what is noble and good to all lesser questions.

@ChristianHummeluhr What is a lay question? By the way this question format was not well praised by others because of its multi questions. But thanks for the support.

@linuxfreebird You took a controversial topic that I think many lay people might have variations on, what with the rise of pick up artistry, and asked it in a way that an appropriate cogsci answer was possible. The votes suggest it was reasonably well-received for this site? IMO this question is right up there with the Lumosity takedown.

@ChristianHummeluhr Thanks. By the way what is the Lumosity takedown?

@linuxfreebird It's our most viewed question (177k views). http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/how-valid-is-lumositys-brain-performance-index-and-what-normative-information-i
